# Using a single symbol from kpfonts

Tags: symbols, packages, kpfonts

I would need some help by extracting the "\varprod"-symbol from the kpfonts package. Similar to how it is done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font) for the subset-symbol of the mathabx package.
Although there is a description how to do it, I can't get my head around the code. Help would be appreciated a lot.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

You have to do some chasing in `kpfonts.sty` to arrive at

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsA}{U}{jkpexa}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbolsA}{bold}{U}{jkpexa}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varprod}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{16}

\begin{document}
\[
\varprod_{i=1}^n A_i\ne\prod_{i=1}^n A_i
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

### The steps

1. Look for `\varprod` in `kpfonts.sty`; this shows the third code line above

   ```
   \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\varprod}{\mathop}{largesymbolsA}{16}
   ```

   (the `re@` part must be removed)
2. Look for the definition of `largesymbolsA` which leads to the other two lines of code

   ```
   \DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbolsA}{U}{jkp\kp@famillem exa}{m}{n}
   \SetSymbolFont{largesymbolsA}{bold}{U}{jkp\kp@famillem exa}{bx}{n}
   ```
3. Finding what `\kp@famillem` means, but it's used for supplying an `l` if the light fonts are requested, otherwise it does nothing.

   ```
   \ifkp@lightmath
     \def\kp@famillem{l}
   \else
     \def\kp@famillem{}
   \fi
   ```
4. Test.
5. Hurray!